# Signal Processing Convolution Summation Calculation

Tags: signal-processing, convolution

I am learning convolution of signals, and need to do a lot of summations and math. Because y[n]=Sum(x[k]h[n-k]) from negative infinity to infinity. I am always stuck at math procedures. Also, I am sure there will be tons of other math tricks in Fourier Transform and such. The professor has no time to do example problems in class. Where can I find more examples of convolution computation? What math books should I read that might be helpful? Do I have to have a strong math background to learn signal processing? Thanks very much!

Answer (score 0):

If you feel that your math background is not strong enough but you want to learn signal processing, then the book i recommend is Richard Lyon's "Understanding Digital Signal Processing". As the author says in the introduction, the only prerequisite to understanding DSP at a first level is knowledge of what a sinusoid is, and enthusiasm!